# Помогите с скриптом

Tags: python, случайные-числа, бот, discord

Делаю дискорд бота,при компиляции выводит следующую ошибку

```
D:\Python>py bot.py
```

File "bot.py", line 32
    if (num=1):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Сам код

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import random
import random
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'NTY5NDYwMDgyMTY1ODA5MTUz.XMSi8A.ZzeuHNushB0iACjou3QWP9iI8ek'

client = discord.Client()


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return


        if message.content.startswith( '?cat'):
            response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
            data = response.json()
            await message.channel.send(data['file'])

        num=random.randit(1,2)
        if (num=1):
            await message.channel.send('Вым выпал Орёл')
            else await message.channel.send('Вам выпала Решка')

        if message.content.startswith('?hi'):
            await message.channel.send('Привет '+ format(message.author.mention)+ ' ты крутой!')

        if message.content.startswith('?help'):jg
            await message.channel.send('Мои команды \n •?hi - Если ты еще сегодня не скем не здоровался,я сделаю это вместо твоих друзей.\n •?сat-получить рандомную фотографию(или ГИФку) кошки. ')

        #if message.content.startswith('?hi'):
        #   await message.channel.send('Привет {0} ты крутой!'.author)





client = MyClient()

client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Для проверки условия используется ==(двойное равно)

Comment: Не компиляции, а интерпритации*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде вы используете строку

```
if (num=1):
```

Исправьте ее на

```
if num == 1:
```

Так же у вас есть опечатка, которая тоже приведет к ошибке

```
if message.content.startswith('?help'): jg
```

Исправьте ее на

```
if message.content.startswith('?help'):
```

И еще у вас есть строка

```
else await message.channel.send('Вам выпала Решка')
```

Перепишите ее вот так

```
else:
    await message.channel.send('Вам выпала Решка')
```